# Uncommenting code only for junit

Tags: web-services, junit, weblogic, jdeveloper

How can I tell JUnit to skip certain lines of source code?

Context: I'm programming a WebService which uses the weblogic.logging.LoggingHelper class to create log entries.

Calls to this class are only useful, if the code runs on a weblogic server. But I want to test the code locally, without having to uncomment the logging statements for debugging all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to avoid calling the LoggingHelper, you should use mocking framework like mockito where in you can mock the weblogic.logging.LoggingHelper class and avoid calling the real method.

```
LoggingHelper lh = Mockito.mock(LoggingHelper.class);
when(lh.log(anyString()).thenReturn(...);
```

Here is the link to the framrwork
https://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You have to either use a mocking framework like ashoka suggested or you have to rewrite your production code such that you can easily exchange the LoggingHelper.